# How to set, get and validate sessions in JSF like PHP $_SESSION['']

Tags: session, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

Please help me. I am new in JSF and from PHP background. I want to prevent  unauthorized users from accessing pages like dashboard, Profiles etc and want to redirect them to the login page directly from .xhtml file. I know the flow of web well cause i did many projects with PHP. Now I am working on JSF project. I am searching on web and doing everything step by step, but I didn't get any satisfactory answer for my question there are many examples for JSF login but I didn't get how I redirect unauthorized users to the login page from any .xhtml page.

Comment: You could also checkout j_security_check, I use it in my current project and I really like it.